# ActiveMQ Artemis Anycast and Multicast prefix

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-artemis

I'm using ActiveMQ Artemis version 2.6.2 and using Apache Camel to route messages.

When I connect Camel with jms-component in AMQ, for some reason in ActiveMQ Artemis the new queue is created with `jms.queue.` as a prefix.

I know if I add the follow code on acceptor in `broker.xml` the problem is solved. But sadly I don't have access to do that.

`anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.`

Is there a way to solve this in Java Code? I tried these steps but no success.

```
from("amq:QUEUE.TEST").setProperty("anycastPrefix", simple("jms.queue."))
from("amq:jms:queue:QUEUE.TEST")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that the queue is being created with the `jms.queue.` prefix is almost certainly because Camel is using an Artemis **1.x** client instead of a 2.x client. The 1.x client is hard-coded to use the `jms.queue.` and `jms.topic.` prefixes.

As you note, the simplest way to solve this issue is by configuring the prefixes on the appropriate acceptor in `broker.xml`. I don't know of any way to solve this issue in Java code. I think your best bet would be just to upgrade the Artemis client implementation which Camel is using.

Comment: I upgraded the Artemis Client from 1.3 to 2.6.2 and still get prefix jms.queue. on queues. I need to some something else?

Comment: Nothing in the Artemis 2.x client will use a prefix by default. Therefore I suspect that either you didn't actually upgrade the client library appropriately or you're manually setting the prefix somehow.

Comment: I just updated the dependency artemis-jms-client, artemis-core-client and to 2.6.2 in my pom.xml and I confirmed that the packaged was generate with these versions.

Comment: Can you create a repo on GitHub with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Hi @Justin, you were right. On my machine the build was getting the version 2.6.2, But in the server the Jenkins was getting the cached version 1.3.0. Solved the cache problem is gone. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for following up. I was pretty puzzled earlier.  :)